# How to create JsonArray using loop?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JsonArray using a loop and adding the loop index to value, but getting last index in the JsonArray.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    item.put("information", "test"+i);
    item.put("id", 0+i);
    item.put("subName", "course"+i);
    //System.out.println(item.toString());
    array.add(item);
    System.out.println(array.toString());
}
```

Expected result:

```
[{"subName":"course0","information":"test0","id":0},
{"subName":"course1","information":"test1","id":1}]
```

Actual result:

```
[{"subName":"course1","information":"test1","id":1},{"subName":"course1","information":"test1","id":1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only creates one `JSONObject` and then keeps modifying it. The following example illustrates this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
item.put("id", 0); 
array.add(item); 
// The next line overwrites the "id" in item. This also affects 
// the one already in the array because it's the same instance
item.put("id", 1); 
array.add(item); 
System.out.println(array.toString());
```

The array now contains the same instance twice. Result: `[{"id":0}, {"id":0}]`

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item1 = new JSONObject();
item1.put("id", 0); 
array.add(item1); 
JSONObject item2 = new JSONObject();
item2.put("id", 1); 
array.add(item2); 
System.out.println(array.toString());
```

The array now contains two distinct instances. Result: `[{"id":0}, {"id":1}]`

In your code, you can solve the problem by moving the creation of the `JSONObject` instances into the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    JSONObject item = new JSONObject(); // moved inside loop
    item.put("information", "test"+i);
    ...
    array.add(item); //
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it's working but I have one doubt as item.put uses HashMap so it's suppose to override the Id value to 1 right Output:- Result: [{"id":1}]

Comment: You mean in the loop? The thing is that a *new* instance is created on every iteration (in the code in my answer). The `put` operation only affects that instance and not the one created in the previous iteration of the loop. In your original code, there is only one instance of `JSONObject` and there, `put` is called on that same instance repeatedly, overwriting the previous values every time which is why you get the output you describe.